# Draw zones instead of of points on an radar image

Tags: c++, image, qt, transformation

I don't really know how to explain it in a better way, so please look at the following images :

[This is what I create for the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB2uu.jpg)

[This is what I whish to create instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmkM.jpg)

I am currently using C++ with Qt 4.8.

Do you know a way that would allow me to reach my goal ? Using a library or a transformation matrix ? Or something else ?

I am a total newbie to image manipulation, so every advice is precious for me.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I draw each colored pixel from Lat/Long measures, if it can help.

Comment: It seems that you want to fill the defined polygonal area. You have to outline them first, which might be a little bit complicated. Perhaps you can take a look at this [lecture file](http://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.tufts.edu%2F~sarasu%2Fcourses%2Fcomp175-2009fa%2Fpdf%2Fcomp175-06-color-texture.pdf&ei=E_KrU7aRHIe6lAX-_oH4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEGk0zSjsI21Fu7fPrXVfe5Wq_jBw&bvm=bv.69837884,d.dGI&cad=rja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use what is called a morphological operator. In this case, you would require the 'open' operator. OpenCV provides a pretty good implementation (and documentation of these) which can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html).

Comment: This solution seems pretty interesting to me ! Going to try it immediately !

Answer (score 0):

Draw circles instead of points is all I can think of. Creating a triangle mesh is tricky with the concave elements of the distribution.

EDIT: Just looked at the full size version of the image and wondered if the data set is stored radially? You could scan adjacent radial lines and try to match up the changes in value along each line to form a set of quads. There will be a large number of edge conditions to consider though.

EDIT2: Alternatively, form a uniformly distributed set of quads and interpolate the vertex colours.

Comment: it is a solution I have thought of, but doing so I will loose precision near the center of the image :/ But if there is no other solution this waht I will do I think

Comment: effectively, at the beginning the data is stored radialy, but it is tranformed immediately in Lat/Long.

Comment: @Karalix: Leave it radial until after forming the mesh.

Comment: I didn't understand all the words you said in your EDIT2 ^^' can you explain it to me a bit more ?

Comment: @Karalix: Every n-pixels along each radial line, calculate a colour value based on the nearest samples and use the result to form a corner of a quad.

Answer (score 0):

you can start by increasing the size of the points,

you could create a triangle mesh by using a sweepline algorithm:

sort the points by lat

keep a subset sorted by long

when you add a point compare to the 4 adjacent points and add triangles to the "to draw" set (remove points too far away from the current lat as needed)

with opengl you can use an index buffer to hold which point should be drawn